# Python 3 - Check a list of user inputs for multiples of 5

Tags: list, function, python-3.6, defined

How can I check a list of user inputted values for multiples of 5? I need to be able to print what percentage of these values are multiples of 5. For example:

```
 intList = [5, 10, 11, 15]
 "75% of values in intList are multiples of 5"
```

Here's my code so far:

```
 intList = []

 running = True
 while running:
   intAmount = int(input("Enter the amount of integers you are inputting: "))
   if intAmount > 0:
     running = False


 for i in range (intAmount):
   integers = int(input("Enter an integer here: "))
   intList.append(integers)
 print(intList)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Code:***

```
intList = [int(x) for x in input('Enter list of numbers: ').split()]
count = 0

for num in intList:
    if (num % 5) == 0:
        count+=1

percent = (count / len(intList)) * 100
print("%.2f%% of values in intList are multiples of 5"%percent)
```

***Input:***

Enter the numbers *`separated by space`*.

```
Enter list of numbers: 4 6 2 10 9 45
```

***Output:***

```
33.33% of values in intList are multiples of 5
```

**Code 2:**
(As requested by user)

```
intList = []

running = True
while running:
    intAmount = int(input("Enter the amount of integers you are inputting: "))
    if intAmount > 0:
        running = False


for i in range (intAmount):
    integers = int(input("Enter an integer here: "))
    intList.append(integers)
print(intList)

count = 0
for num in intList:
    if (num % 5) == 0:
        count+=1

percent = (count / len(intList)) * 100
print("%.2f%% of values in intList are multiples of 5"%percent)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use that function in my current program _without_ changing the way I input the integers?

Comment: Yes you can do it. Just append the `count = 0

for num in intList:
    if (num % 5) == 0:
        count+=1

percent = (count / len(intList)) * 100
print("%.2f%% of values in intList are multiples of 5"%percent)` to you code in the question and that should do the trick.

Comment: I have added a `code 2` section in the answer for you reference.